# XXClone as a tool for migrating Windows XP Home from PATA to SATA HD

Tags: windows-xp, operating-systems, migration, clone

Has anybody had any experience using **XXClone** as a tool for cloning an existing installation of Windows in order to move it from an old PATA drive to a new, larger SATA without having to reinstall everything? Did you have any problems? Or can you recommend an alternative (free) software tool that you know - preferably from repeated experience - is reliable?

I'm looking to move Windows XP Home SP3 to a new disk: same file system, same partition size.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have specific experience for this procedure, I think it would work, but mind one thing, win xp don't support SATA drive natively, it needs an additional driver. This issue has been resolved with newer motherboard that can be configured to run SATA drives as IDE, before doing this procedure I would try to install winxp from disc to the SATA drive, if the procedure starts you are good to go, otherwise find the driver for your SATA drive model and install it in your old drive, THEN clone with XXClone.

Comment: Thanks oplus1, I was aware of the problem with WXP and SATA drivers but it wouldn't have occurred to me that I needed to load the SATA driver onto the drive to be cloned first. This is exactly the kind of info I was looking for.